# Line equation tangent to convex level curve

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization, curves, economics

Suppose we are given a differentiable function $f(x,y)$ such that $\forall$ $t \in \mathbb{R}$, $f = t$ yields strictly convex level curves. If we are given a line equation $L:y = mx + c$ such that it always intersects two points of a level curve or is tangent to it or does not intersect at all, will it mean that a level curve tangent to $y = mx + c$ always exists?

This is required for a different (convex optimization) problem that I am trying to solve. I am not sure if this holds, but intuitively it feels like that, although I don't have a solid intuition to solve this. Using the Mean Value Theorem, one can say that a tangent with slope $m$ exists that will intersect a given level curve. But I can't extend this to prove that the line $y = mx + c$ itself will be tangent to some level curve.

**Update:** The problem is almost solved (thanks to @copper.hat), but there's a case that I can rule out. Please see ***my*** last comment below this post.

Comment: Let $L$ be the line. Pick some $t \in f(L)$. By assumption $L \cap f^{-1}(\{t\})$ is tangent or intersects at two points $p_1,p_2$. If tangent you are finished, otherwise find an extreme point of $f$ on the segment $[p_1,p_2]$. At this point $p^*$ you must have $\nabla f(p^*)$ perpendicular to $L$.

Comment: In general, no.

Comment: @copper.hat I was reading the solution and I don't think I understand it very well. You're choosing $t$ such that $f=t$ and $f(x,y) = t$ for some $(x,y) \in L$. But then, what exactly is $L \cap f^{-1}(\{t\})$? To me, it seems to be the intersection of the line $L$ and the points $(x,y)$ that form the particular level curve $f=t$. This means the intersection is basically one point or two points. But your statement "is tangent or intersects at two points" appears as if you're referring to the level curve rather than a point or two. Can you clarify this part for me please?

Comment: If the intersection is at one point then the line is tangent to the curve $f=t$. If the intersection is two points, then on the closed segment joining these two points there is an extremum of $f$. This corresponds to some curve $f=t'$, and must consist of exactly one point, so we are back to the first case.

Comment: @copper.hat Suppose the line intersects the tangent at two points. You find the extreme point of the convex level curve and note that $\nabla f(p^{*})$ is perpendicular to $L$. But I need to show that a level curve exists whose tangent is $L$. In your case, the two may not even intersect. They’re only perpendicular.

Comment: Read what I wrote. At the extremum, $f=t'$, and there can only be one point of intersection. Hence $f=t'$ is tangent to $L$.

Comment: @copper.hat I’m sorry I don’t understand how you’re choosing the extremum and how you’re solving the problem. But thank you.

Comment: If the line intersects at two points, it forms a natural segment. Find the $\max$ or $\min$ of $f$ on this segment, at least one will be in the relative interior of the segment. Since it is an extremum, the gradient of $f$ must be perpendicular to the segment at that point.

Comment: @copper.hat Do you mean this: $\displaystyle\max/\min_{\substack{x \in [p_1,p_2] \\ y \in \mathbb{R}}} f(x,y)$?

Comment: I mean $\min$/$\max$ of $f(x)$ for $x \in [p_1,p_2]$. I am using $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Replace $x$ by $(x_1,x_2)$ or $(x,y)$ in the above. $[p_1,p_2] = \{ t p_1 +(1-t)p_2 \mid t \in [0,1] \}$, and $p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @copper.hat Now I get what you mean. But there's a case that I am trying to rule out: [Consider this image](https://i.imgur.com/Nk9Gm0N.png). What if $f=$ both the min and the max (or one of the two that is supposed to be the tangent) intersect at two points? Is this not possible at all?

Comment: If either the min or max intersect at two points, then since the level sets are convex, all the points in between must be min/max which contradicts the hypothesis.

Comment: @copper.hat Contradicts which hypothesis? My question was, what if the max and min are like I drew, and every other level curve $(f = t : t \in f([p_1,p_2]))$ has the value of $t$ between the max and the min? (This is probably not possible but I don't know why or why not that is the case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Why is the graph below impossible?

[image: aa]

Let $\displaystyle m_1=\min_{p\in[p_1,p_2]}f(p)$ and $\displaystyle m_2=\max_{p\in[p_1,p_2]}f(p)$. WLOG, let the two outer intersection points in the graph be $p_1$ and $p_2$ from left to right, i.e., $f(p_1)=f(p_2)=m_2$. Let the inner two points be $A$ and $B$ from left to right, i.e., $f(A)=f(B)=m_1$. We have $m_1<m_2$; otherwise, the line intersects the level curve $f(x,y)=m_1$ at those four points.

Let $E$ be the midpoint between $A$ and $B$.

- $f(E) = m_1$. The level curve that passes through $E$ also passes $A$ and $B$.
- $f(E) > m_1$. The level curve $f(x,y)=\min(f(E),m_2)$ passes a point between $p_1$ and $A$ that is not $A$, a point between $A$ and $E$, a point between $B$ and $p_2$.

However, any strictly convex curve intersects with any line at no more than $2$ points. Hence, the graph above is impossible.

Please see a complete proof below, anyway, if you read the graph differently.

##### A complete proof

Given point $A\in\mathbb R^2$, let its coordinate be $(A_x, A_y)$ and $f(A)=f(A_x,A_y)$ by slight abuse of $f$. Let $\mathcal C_A$ be the level curve of $f$ that passes $A$, i.e. the curve defined by the equation $f(x,y)=f(A)$.

Pick an abitrary point $P\in \mathcal L$. Since $P\in \mathcal L\cap \mathcal C_P$, by assumption, $|\mathcal L\cap \mathcal C_P|=2$ or $\mathcal L$ is tangent to $\mathcal C_P$. If it is the latter case, we are done.

Otherwise, $|\mathcal L\cap \mathcal C_P|=2$. Let $Q\in \mathcal L\cap \mathcal C_P$, $Q\not=P$. WLOG, suppose $P_x<Q_x$; otherwise, just switch $P$ and $Q$.

$f$ on line segment $\overline{PQ}$ cannot be constant; otherwise, $\mathcal L\cap\mathcal C_P$ would contain infinitely many points. There are two cases.

- The minimum value of $f$ on $\overline{PQ}$ is smaller than $f(P)$.
  Suppose the minimum value is reached at $S$ for some $S\in\overline{PQ}$. Then $f(S)\lt f(P)$, $S\not=P$ and $S\not=Q$.

  **Claim**. Let $B\in \mathcal L$, $B\not=S$. Then $f(S)\lt f(B)$.
  **Proof**. Let $g(x):x\to \mathbb R$, $g(x)=f(\text{the point on $\mathcal L$ with first coordinate }x)$.  $g(P_x)=f(P)=f(Q)=g(Q_x)$.

  Suppose $f(S)\ge f(B)$ for the sake of contradiction. There are several cases of $B_x$.

  - $B_x<P_x$.

    $\quad\quad\begin{matrix}\mathcal L:\ \\\ \end{matrix} \overline{\quad\quad B\quad\quad P\quad\quad\phantom{B}\quad\phantom{D}\quad S\quad \quad\quad Q\quad\quad\quad}$

    Since $g$ is continuous, $g(x)=\frac{f(S)+f(P)}2$ as an equation in $x$ has one root in interval $(B_x, P_x)$, a root in interval $(P_x, S_x)$ and a root in interval $(S_x, Q_x)$. That means $\mathcal L$ intersects the level curve $f(x,y)=\frac{f(S)+f(P)}2$ at three points, which cannot be true.
  - $B_x = P_x$, which is not possible since $f(S)<f(P)$.
  - $P_x<B_x<S_x$. Since $g(S_x)$ is the minimum value of $g$ on $[P_x, Q_x]$, $f(S)\le f(B)$. Hence $f(S)=f(B)$.
    Let $D$ be the midpoint of $B$ and $S$.
    $\quad\quad\begin{matrix}\mathcal L:\ \\\ \end{matrix} \overline{\quad\quad\phantom{B}\quad\quad P\quad\quad B\quad D\quad S\quad\quad\quad Q\quad\quad\quad}$

    - If $f(S)=f(D)$, then $\mathcal L$ intersects the level curve $\mathcal C_S$ at $B, D, S$, which cannot be true.
    - Otherwise, $f(S) < f(D)$ since $g(S_x)$ is the minimum value of $g$ on $[P_x, Q_x]$. Then $g(x)=\frac{f(S)+\min(f(P), f(D))}2$ as an equation in $x$ has one root in interval $(P_x, B_x)$, one root in interval $(B_x, D_x)$ and one root in interval $(D_x,S_x)$. That cannot be true.
  - The remaining cases are symmetric to the cases above. $\quad\checkmark$

  The claims says $\mathcal L$ intersects $\mathcal C_S$ only at $S$. That means $\mathcal L$ is tangent to $\mathcal C_S$.
- The minimum value of $f$ on $\overline{PQ}$ is bigger than $f(P)$.
  This case is symmetric to the case above.

Proof is completed.

Comment: This answer basically elaborates [the comment by copper.hat](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403325/line-equation-tangent-to-convex-level-curve/4412335#comment9211122_4403325). Note that this answer only requires $f$ be continuous instead of differentiable. Also we can define "a line is tangent to a curve" in whatever reasonable way; the conclusion still stands.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I need some time to read and understand this completely. I have a tight schedule today, so I will read it tomorrow. Once again, thank you! (I'll most certainly accept it and award you the bounty even if new answers pour in, once I read it fully, that is, tomorrow.)

Comment: Can you tell me where does $C$ come from in the first part? (You have mentioned $E$ is the midpoint of $B$ and $C$.)

Comment: @dictatemetokcus Updated.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus Is there any problem with my complete proof? I am afraid that the bounty might be wasted. By the way, that $C$ was a typo. I have updated the answer to be much clearer. Please note $\mathcal L$ in the answer means the line $L$ in the question.

Comment: Apologies! To keep my word and for your efforts, I have started another bounty (which I can award only after 24 hours, apparently). In the first part, $f(x,y) = \min(f(E), m_2)$ is unnecessary, right? You simply could have written $f = f(E)$ I think, as $f(E) \leq m_2$ always.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I should have written "the level curve $f(x,y)=f(E)$". (I was too attached to the mental model in my complete proof.) I will update later in case there are more minor lapses.

Comment: No problem! \8char